# apt upgrade - connection reset by peer

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

Pretty fresh Jammy installation. No changes done in the setup whatsoever. I was able to `apt update` without problems. No proxy. No VPN.
What I tried:

- two different WiFis
- waiting a week in case the problem was on server side
- adding fix-missing flag as suggested
- apt-get update -> nothing to update
- apt-get upgrade -> same result
- upgrading those packages one by one -> it looks like apt is trying to update them all at once anyway, with the same error

  ```
  ewa@ewa-desktop:~$ sudo apt upgrade
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree... Done
  Reading state information... Done
  Calculating upgrade... Done
  The following packages will be upgraded:
    libldap-2.5-0 libldap-common linux-firmware python3-update-manager
    update-manager update-manager-core
  6 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  Need to get 267 MB/268 MB of archives.
  After this operation, 466 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
  Get:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29 [267 MB]
  Ign:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29
  Get:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29 [267 MB]
  Ign:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29
  Get:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29 [267 MB]
  Ign:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29
  Get:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29 [267 MB]
  Ign:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29
  Get:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29 [267 MB]
  Err:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29
    Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer) [IP: 153.19.251.225 80]
  E: Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.29_all.deb  Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer) [IP: 153.19.251.225 80]
  E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
  ```

Comment: Are you connecting through a VPN? If so that might be the culprit

Comment: no. added that information to the question

Comment: Try another repository ...

Comment: @SorenA which and how?

Comment: In the Software Updater app, under Settings... you can choose between known repositories/mirrors. Choose the Ubuntu main repo.

Comment: @SorenA it helped, thank you very much! please post as answer so I can upvote and accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Software Updater app, under Settings... you can choose between known repositories/mirrors.

Choose another repository than the one you are using now, t.ex. the Ubuntu main repo., but any one will do I think.